# Polynomial approximability of functions with kink (hat functions)

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, approximation-theory

Does anyone know where to find results on the optimal polynomial approximability of functions such as
$$
f(x):=\|x\|, x\in[-1,1]^d,
$$
or $$
f(x):=\frac{1}{1+\|x\|}, x\in[-1,1]^d?
$$

That is, for example for $ d=1$, I am interested in upper and lower bounds for 
$$
\inf_{p\in P_k}\|f-p\|_{L^p}
$$
as $ k\to\infty $ ( $ p\in {2,\infty}$). Here $ P_k $  are polynomials of degree equal to or less than $ k $.

For $ d> 1$ I would be interested in similar results for any type of polynomial space you may offer.

Comment: What is your definition of "optimal", there is no unique definition?

Comment: As you probably know, any continuous function on a compact product of intervals can be approximated by multivariate polynomials. When you ask about "optimal" approximability, are you interested in computing such approximations?  Or in estimating the error a priori for bounded degrees?

Comment: Sorry for the very incomplete first version of the question. I hope the edited version answers both of your questions